# Combining two methods of MFA in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I'm interested in whether I can configure both methods of 2FA for my app in B2C? So that a user can then choose how he wants to sign in: with MFA via SMS or via authenticator app

Comment: I´m also interested in this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it. You can use [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone) template as starter template. It enables user to choose MFA method between SMS and Email.
In your case you can modify the custom policy to instead of Email, use MS Authenticator app like presented in [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/totp) sample.
Then user can choose the method. With custom policies you have the flexibility, it means that you can ask user about preferred MFA method during the registration flow or after first login operation. End result looks like this:

[image]